# Machine Learning - How to predict set of fixed fields based on past features

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction

I have quite a large dataset (> 100k rows), which contains information for logistical shipments. (export shipments)

The dataset looks like this:

```
|shipper|consignee                    |origin|destination                                  |
|-------|-----------------------------|------|---------------------------------------------|
|6409292|288882                       |USSFO |CNPVG                                        |
|6409292|288882                       |USSFO |CNPVG                                        |
|6409292|182724                       |USSFO |HKHKG                                        |
|6409292|182724                       |USSFO |HKHKG                                        |
|8201922|948292                       |USSFO |FRCDG                                        |
|8201922|948292                       |USSFO |FRCDG                                        |
|8201922|948292                       |USSFO |FRNIC                                        |
|8201922|291222                       |USEWR |AEDXB                                        |
```

So what we have here is a list of past shipments. It shows the relationship between shipper and consignee, and from where the shipment was from and where it was sent to.

Based on this past data, I wish to be able to predict when a new shipment is added by looking at the `consignee code` and `origin`.

## Example

Take below new booking as an example:

```
|shipper|consignee                    |origin|destination                                  |
|-------|-----------------------------|------|---------------------------------------------|
|1234567|948292                       |USMOB |?                                            |
```

How can I train a model to predict the `destination`? And what is this area in ML referred to?

Comment: This is a single class classification problem. You can use sklearn or XGBoost libraries to train it, setting destination as predictable feature (usually "y" in sklearn). Also, you will have to make sure that the algorithm takes consignee as categorical variable and not numerical. However, if you only have those 3 variables and such a small amount of data, I wouldn't expect great results

Comment: @JavierLópezTomás Thank you! I ultimatley have a lot of more columns, that I will take into consideration and a lot more rows (>100k that is growing).

Do you have any recommendations on how to get started training a model with XGBoost or sklearn?

Comment: @oliverbj this is a simple use-case. I have a feeling that the Extra Tree classifier algorithm will work for your case. You can find all the details regard the Extra Tree classifier algorithm here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier.html and https://towardsdatascience.com/an-intuitive-explanation-of-random-forest-and-extra-trees-classifiers-8507ac21d54b. But do remember that you have to do some data pre-processing.

Answer (score 3):

Before diving into machine learning, understanding the concepts is important:

- Dataset: This is your collection of data that contains columns and a `target` column wich we want to predict.
- Problem type: This is the problem that we are facing. Please check the following link that explains more about it: [problem types](https://www.practicalai.io/categorizing-machine-learning-problems/).
- Metric: This is to evaluate the performance of our model, and you have to choose one in order to evaluate it properly. For example, if you have `True` or `False` you may want to be penalized everytime your model makes a mistake as if he goes for `True` as answer he may get 50% right and thats a model with `0.5` accuracy wich is not correct as it only answers `True`. I hope that this [post](https://medium.com/thalus-ai/performance-metrics-for-classification-problems-in-machine-learning-part-i-b085d432082b) helps you to understand better.
- Cross Validation: [crossvalidation sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html).
- Train and test splits: We split our dataset in to piece were we will use some part of the data to `train` and other to `test` or evaluate our model.

Most of this can be done with the popular library `sklearn`, in the following example:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, train_test_split

dataset = load_iris()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    dataset.data, dataset.target, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
# No corss validation
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)

# With cross validation
model = RandomForestClassifier()
accuracy_scorer = make_scorer(accuracy_score)

scores = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, scoring=accuracy_scorer)
scores.mean()
```

This example is just a very simple one where the data is processed and simple, also the problem is being solved in most of the cases with a `0.9` accuracy. You will probably have to dive more in order to solve a problem with more columns than just those. My suggestion is to dive in [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions) and look for notebooks or kernels with examples where people process some kind of dataset and obtain a baseline for a given problem and you may learn new topics like `OneHotEncoding` `FeatureExtractions` and many more.

Also there ara libraries that do this for you, or automate it and can solve a classification problem, check out [MLBlocks](https://hdi-project.github.io/MLBlocks/) or [ATM](https://hdi-project.github.io/ATM/).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! How do I load a csv file for example to the code you have given? If I have a file called `shipments.csv`?

Comment: You have to use `pandas`. `df = pandas.read_csv('shipments.csv')` and then you have to create `target=df.pop('destination')` and finaly `train_test_split(df, target)`

Comment: How can I test my model with new data? I have successfully gotten an accuracy of 0.70. How can I test it with data it has never seen before?

Comment: By generating predictions, `model.predict(X)` where `X` is the new data. Make sure that, if the new data has the `target` column to do the `target = df.pop('target')` and use that target to validate, basicly your `X_test` is your new data without the target and `target` is your `y_test`.